# Flutter update circular chart hold label with redux store

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and want to ask a question regarding redux and [circular chart](https://github.com/xqwzts/flutter_circular_chart). I have the following code. I tried different ways but none of them work. I have labelled the places where do not work in the code below.

```
class CurrentTabPageState extends State<CurrentTabPage> {

int _angle = 0;
final GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState> _chartKey = new GlobalKey<AnimatedCircularChartState>();

List<CircularStackEntry> data = <CircularStackEntry>[
  new CircularStackEntry(
    <CircularSegmentEntry>[
      new CircularSegmentEntry(50.0, Colors.red[200], rankKey: 'Q1'),
      new CircularSegmentEntry(1000.0, Colors.green[200], rankKey: 'Q2')
    ],
    rankKey: 'Quarterly Profits',
  ),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new StoreConnector<ReduxState, double>(
    converter: (store) { setState(() {
      _angle = store.state.angle.toInt();
      print(_angle);     <------- Can print correct value here
    });
      return store.state.angle;
    },
    builder: (context, angle) {
      print(_angle);     <------- Can print correct value here
      return new AnimatedCircularChart(
          key: _chartKey,
          size: const Size(300.0, 300.0),
          initialChartData: data,
          chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
          holeLabel: '$_angle',   <----- does not updated
          //holeLabel: 'angle',   <----- does not updated
          labelStyle: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: _angle*10.roundToDouble(),   <---- does not updated
          )
      );
    });
}}
```

Can anyone please give some suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does `correct value` mean?

Comment: `correct value` means the printed value is as expected. More specifically, when the value in state is changed, the printed value is changed as well. However, the lines showing "does not update" means when the value in state is changed, the value in those lines does not change.

Comment: Is `store.state.angle.toInt()` as expected?

Comment: yes, it is as expected